# Flaws in the Stack Exchange system. How to deal with them?

Tags: support, post-ban

So, after being a user for well over a year, it has become apparent to me that while there are many helpful, wonderful people on this site, there are also incredibly pedantic people that downvote answers and questions based on small, if existent, nitpicks. [image: Downvoted answer]

A blatant example is in the image above, in which my answer is the one chosen as the official answer, and yet has a downvote anyway.

I wouldn't particularly mind this if the system weren't rigged with a lack of ways to appeal and the fact that your ability to ask questions is removed (without warning) if you get too many downvotes.

I lost my ability to ask questions on the Stack Overflow site and despite many months passing, improving my existing questions, and getting hundreds of points from my answers on others' queries, still the ban remains.

In conclusion, if anyone has any advice for appealing to the Stack Exchange admins or less vague advice on how to remove the ban (the admins say to "improve" your queries and the users should upvote according to this, but this doesn't happen), that would be amazing. Thanks ^_^

Comment: I wouldn't downvote that answer (especially since it apparently worked), but my guess for why it got a downvote is that there wasn't much explanation with it. Give a sentence or two about why it works.

Comment: My point was that the Stack Exchange put too much faith in their users making the correct decision.

Comment: *"in which my answer is the one chosen as the official answer"* correction: it is only the answer that the author of the question accepted. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Gimby That's an argument of semantics. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Not trying to be nit picky but a single down vote should not get you question banned.  I doubt we will ever know the criteria but you need to have a decent amount of negative content(down votes) to get banned.  You should have also been warned and throttled before the ban.  It is hard to write a good question but if you expect a good answer then we expect a good question.

Comment: Actually all answers on that question pretty much suck equally, no explanations, no links to documentation, no mention of possible exceptions / TryParse etc.

Comment: @Rariolu Gimby's point is that often the OP is sometimes the worst person to choose the best answer.  Often they select the first answer that works.  But just because it works for the OP doesn't mean that it is the best way to do something, or will always work.  That's why the post score is often a better measure of the correctness of an answer

Comment: It doesn't look like [you took action on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158256/how-to-access-richtextbox-select-method-while-referring-to-it-as-a-control#comment33739007_22158256)? I expect the down voters there to agree with the commenter as there is no edit on that post.

Comment: *or less vague advice on how to remove the ban* - your down voted and deleted questions all read along the same lines of: "I'm trying to do something in C# with MIDI - can someone do it for me please?". You don't appear to have made any effort to edit them to warrant upvoting. In fact, the only effort I see of you trying to get out of a ban is saying *I'm trying to get my ability to ask questions back, I've done all I can for this question so can someone please vote or comment.* in [this deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33928823) - you also don't appear to have taken notes of the..

Comment: ... comments on that giving advice on how to improve the question...

Comment: Every suggestion given to you on that question was dismissed as "too trivial". Users are trying to help you there, but apparently, you refuse to listen.

Comment: The example I gave was one of the more recent ones, it wasn't what got me banned.

Comment: @Rariolu the other 4 deleted answers (-4, -2, -1 and 0 scored) aren't helping either - but since they're all along the same lines as the one I posted... *shrugs*

Comment: Did a certain Jon Skeet come from here?

Comment: Yes, I saw this Meta question and thought you might appreciate a comment on how to help make your question better. You seem to have rejected that suggestion though.

Comment: See, to me these are such nitpicks and don't deserve a downvote.

Comment: I think you should remove the last paragraph of your question: "In conclusion, if anyone has any advice for appealing to the Stack Exchange admins or less vague advice on how to remove the ban (the admins say to "improve" your queries and the users should upvote according to this, but this doesn't happen), that would be amazing." I've given very concrete advice, and you've chosen to ignore it. Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of high quality questions and answers - and the more complete a question is, the clearer it will be for everyone.

Comment: I haven't ignored it, I just disagree.

Comment: Okay, so you feel you're entitled to disagree... but you don't feel that those who are downvoting you are entitled to disagree with you? Interesting. I don't think you've identified any flaws in the system here, unless you believe that everyone who disagrees with you is objectively wrong.

Comment: 'from Liverpool, UK' - I always downvote Kloppa Castle questers anyway :)

Comment: There are always flaws in any system; the trick is to not introduce measures that actually make the system worse.

Comment: The example given by OP looks like an answer to a trivial question about reading strings into a byte.  If it has many dups, someone may have just downvoted all the answers as rep-thinging.

Comment: Although im not from the field of C#, your answer certainly lacks explaination of the code you used. Furthermore... smileys in answers are unprofessional, and the Q you answered is probably a multi-dupe, so I can certainly see why people would.

Comment: @Magisch Oh know, I used an emoji to break from the monotony, how dare I?

Comment: @Rariolu well, this is a professional QA repository, so fluff like that is usually at best distracting. I've edited it a bit to reformulate and remove this fluff.

Comment: Sigh ... This again. So, Stack was meant to be a high level repository of good knowledge about programming. While that one liner answer gives the OP his solution, questions are never about the OP. they should be answered for the next million visitors coming to Stack. In that regards, your answer isn't complete. On one hand, you ask us for tricks... THE top user from the site gave you personalized tips, and you push back. You don't want to improve your questions... You want out of a ban. Listen to what is said by jon and rene, apply it. Then the upvotes will come.

Comment: Oh and replying with snark to people like Magisch here, who is just telling you the agreed upon consensus of the community, will not help your case. For good or worse, this site is community managed. Don't fight everyone from said community, your experience should improve... YMMV, of course

Comment: @Patrice I don't see how this is me fighting, seems like I make a criticism of the users of this site and suddenly get a huge number of downvotes on ancient questions.

Comment: @rariolu not you fighting? You disagree with jon, you reply snarkily to someone telling you "this is usually frowned upon here". You can continue to disagree with the community, for sure. But when the consensus is "code only answers are bad", and you post one....expect the reaction.  And the downvotes since this question: it's called the meta effect. To check the quality of your questions, the most quality minded people of the site looked at your questions. You cast a spotlight on your questions... Some of which are just off topic. Downvotes are to be expected, again.

Comment: The meta effect does go both ways. Highlight a good post on meta, it'll skyrocket in score.

Comment: AHA!  There's the question!  OK, lets see... Googling 'C# Set the value of a byte from a string?' gives: 'About 438,000 results', with the MSDN 'Convert.ToByte Method ' as the very first result.  My conclusion - that question is either LMGTFY laziness or groundbait for rep-PersonalServicesWorkers and it deservers more downvotes than it got.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ it's a bad question which dragged any answers down with it, correct or not.  It is not sick to downvote them.

Comment: I think downvoting a right answer is a bad behavior. I see questions scored -6 with answer(s) socred +5 (just an example). There are malevolent members. Also people tend to upvote when they see many upvotes or downvote questions when they see many downvotes (Pavlov reflex, somehow). Others upvote reputed members for whatever they write and hesitate to upvote good posts of less reputed members.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ well, taken to an, admittedly unrealistic, limit,  a colleague, (or puppet), could post the same question 20,000 times and I could answer each one with the same, correct answer.  Would I deserve rep for that?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ 'Also people tend to upvote when they see many upvotes or downvote questions when they see many downvotes (Pavlov reflex, somehow). Others upvote reputed members for whatever they write and hesitate to upvote good posts of less reputed members' - this has been stated as fact ad-nauseum in dozens of posts.  Unfortunately, nobody has ever been able to actually post any evidence whatsoever that this happens.

Comment: Of course no. Duplicating posts or crossposting is not a right thing to do. To be honest, I did not even check the post the OP is talking about, but what I say is that as long as an answer satisfies the OP and does not mention something dramatically wrong we must not downvote. Personally I never even downvote. I just comment to correct, edit or flag, but never I downvote

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ to be fair, it's quite rare that I downvote answers for being wrong, I am much more likely to downvote answers that are correct, but to a grossly trivial and multi-duped question, and when I do, I don't care what rep the answerers have, I downvote ALL the answers without reading them.

Comment: *I think downvoting a right answer is a bad behavior.* @BillalBEGUERADJ - Forcing an OP to be stuck with an unsalvageable question by answering it (and getting at least one up vote) isn't exactly nice either.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ The OP's checkmark is just "hey, this got me out of my jam". Considering the intent of stack is to keep up the good quality answers that help every next user coming to the question... then yeah, downvoting a question that helped the OP, but is unlikely to help anyone else.... is proper.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're question banned you also need to work on your questions. Let's go over the visible ones once more. This is a to do list. You have to make the changes.

[How to allow a button to stop an action AND have that action affect form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33874814/578411)

- Make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not only a guess from what you think is enough code
- Show how you used the solution with the thread (I'm sure the error you get would make your question a duplicate)
- Add the correct tag (Winforms or WPF)

[How to add scrolling to Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977178/how-to-add-scrolling-to-panel)

- Make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- Add what you tried in the question, don't let that info be burried in comments
- Does any of the answers helped you? If not, why didn't you told them?

[Alternative to "Console.Beep" that allows it to be used multiple times simultaneously (and can synthesis instruments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861660/alternative-to-console-beep-that-allows-it-to-be-used-multiple-times-simultane)

- this is off-topic: learn by heart [What is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

  > Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

[Export musical note data to midi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32796817/578411)

- You only describe here what you have and what you need but no attempt at all to solve it yourself
- If you use the link provide in the comment there and make a start with your implementation first, you can add actual code that you have a problem with in your question instead of just handing over the requirements.

[How to access RichTextBox.Select() method while referring to it as a "Control"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158256/how-to-access-richtextbox-select-method-while-referring-to-it-as-a-control)

- Make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- Follow up on advice given.

To conclude: not much flaws in the system, no need for improvement there...

Comment: I have some sympathy with posters with GUI apps.  An MCVE is often very difficult with such apps since they suck in massive libraries and typically depend on so many other units that is not practical to shove it all into an SO questions format:(.

Comment: @MartinJames Aren't you really saying there that applications which depend on a lot of libraries are hard to MCVE?

Comment: Yyyessss..... ...  (expecting trap)

Comment: @MartinJames No trap, just nitpicking. The theme of this meta :)

Comment: @Gimby as I hit enter, I swear I could hear steel jaws snapping shut on my fingers:)

Comment: @MartinJames: For C#, part of the problem is Visual Studio. It's actually not hard to build (say) a WinForms app entirely in code, and an MCVE can be ~20-30 lines of code. But many posters have never even considered doing that - they rely on the designer autogenerating code for them. WPF may be slightly harder, admittedly... (The other issue is people with GUIs who assume that the problem is GUI-specific when it really isn't. An "ASP.NET" question which is actually just about parsing JSON can easily be demonstrated in a console app...)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes indeed, code is code, and if there is some complex function that implements some algorithm, it does not matter whether it's called from main() or an OnClick() handler, (well, as long as it does not take a long time, anyway).  If it's a problem that is interwoven with GUI operations, then it's more of a problem to post, and anyone who develops  GUI app without a form designer is insa...  misguided anyway:)

Comment: @MartinJames: Oh I wouldn't disagree that a form designer is useful for actual development... but it's a useful skill to be able to demonstrate GUI issues *without* designer cruft. I like examples where I don't need to fire up Visual Studio and create a project in order to reproduce the issue - copy/paste/compile/run with a new text file should be enough :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Idk about you but for myself I can't even code without some form of IDE at all atm (Im still an apprentice but still)

Comment: @Magisch: I do most of my Stack Overflow coding in a simple editor with syntax highlighting only, then compile from the command line. Much quicker than getting VS up :) I "need" an IDE for complex code, mind you.